# yii php how to automatically populate relative table fields

Tags: php, yii, model, relationship

I have  two different tables one is Animal and other is category I have added relationship rules already like:

inside animal model class

```
    return array(
    'category'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
    );
```

inside category model class

```
    return array(
    'animals'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Animal', 'category_id'),
    );
```

an action for create form like below

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Animal;


    if(isset($_POST['Animal']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Animal'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }


    $model = $model->with('category')->find();

    echo $model->category->name;
```

Now here is my question; can I populate automatically the category object? What I am trying is I have created some forms using crud and now I need to use this relationship so that category information should come with the model object. For this purpose I am calling explicitly this condition

```
    $model = $model->with('category')->find();
```

Is there any better way to do it because I don't want to repopulate the whole object?

Comment: I am not sure i understood your question correctly but may be this will help you: (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/)

Comment: And U can set return array(
    'category'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id', 'together' => true),
    );
for populate 'category' model by one sql query

Comment: Thanks everyone i found the answer previously but i will upvote you for sharing same thing that i did.